# Двоичный поиск по массиву примитивов

Tags: java

Есть массив, в котором элементы отсортированы по убыванию

```java
int[] arr = {50, 40, 30, 20, 10};
```

Нужно найти определенный элемент двоичным поиском.

Что пытался делать

```java
int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, 30, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

получаю ошибку, что тип `int[]` не соответствует типу `T[]`.

Если массив объявить как `Integer[] arr`, то проблем не возникает

Задача учебная, поэтому использование других типов не предлагать.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такое решение

```java
int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(
  Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toArray(),
  30,
  Collections.reverseOrder()
);
```

Comment: это решение бессмысленное. зачем нужен какой-то поиск, если в стриме и так весь массив перебирается?

Answer (score 0):

Если задача учебная, то нужно написать метод, в чем, собственно, вопрос:

```
private static int binarySearch(int[] a, int key) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = a.length;
    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        int midVal = a[mid];
        if (midVal > key)low = mid + 1;
        else if (midVal < key) high = mid - 1;
        else return mid;
    }
    return -(low + 1); 
}
```